# Android: Oncreate layout loading on network response

Tags: android

My use-case requires the loading of  layout setcontentview, depending on the network request and the response it receives, I have to load the view on the network response. For eg. *I have teacher layout and student layout. The decission is got from the network. Now the issue I face is when I make network call, it runs on a separate thread and when I send back the message to the uithread and start the setcontentview of the layout, depending on the response it doesn't work.
Any direction or help would be great, Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you sending network requests?

Comment: perform network request on separate thread ....  in success response send broadcast to your respective activity. till than in your activity show progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using LiveData. Make a server call in a separate thread. When your view is created, show a loader and make server call in a different thread (do not make a network call on main thread). Once you make a server call, start observing the results and when you receive the response post the response value using live data and display the results and hide your loader.
Below is the dummy code for you:

// Init the mutable live data

```
private MutableLiveData<Response> networkCallResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

// get the mutable live data result with this

```
public LiveData<Result> getNetworkCallResult() {
        return networkCallResult;
    }
```

In your activity or fragment from where you are doing the network call, call this method getNetworkCallResult() and observe the results using this :

```
getNetworkCallResult().observe(this, s -> {
// perform the action here.
});
```

How to post the value in live data when you receive the results ? Here it is.

```
networkCallResult.postValue(response);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, will check the livedata usage